# How can I call the 'base implementation' of an overridden virtual method?

Tags: c#, oop

Given the following code, is there a way I can call class A's version of method X?

```
class A
{
  virtual void X() { Console.WriteLine("x"); }
}

class B : A
{
  override void X() { Console.WriteLine("y"); }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    A b = new B();
    // Call A.X somehow, not B.X...
  }
```

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Using the C# language constructs, you cannot explicitly call the base function from *outside* the scope of `A` or `B`. If you really need to do that, then there is a flaw in your design - i.e. that function shouldn't be virtual to begin with, or part of the base function should be extracted to a separate non-virtual function.

You can from *inside* B.X however call A.X

```
class B : A
{
  override void X() { 
    base.X();
    Console.WriteLine("y"); 
  }
}
```

But that's something else.

As Sasha Truf points out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30297884/158483), you can do it through IL.
You can probably also accomplish it through reflection, as mhand points out in the comments.

Comment: Calling A.X() from inside B is the only situation I can even see you needing to call it once overriden. Say you had a copy method with base class members, then override it to add copy functionality for new members and call base.copy() inside so all gets copied.

Comment: Interesting,I would have thought it could be accomplished via reflection?

Comment: When writing tests, its not unusual to want to modify behavior through polymorphic tricks. As such, needing to call base methods from within a overridden method does not necessarily indicate bad design -- it might indicate design that is hard to test. I came across your answer exactly due to such needs.

Comment: @PéturIngiEgilsson - When you write, "call base methods from within a overridden method", I think there is a difference between what you write there, and what the OP, that was calling the base method from *outside* the derived class. As I understood your comment, you are talking about calling the method from *inside* the derived class, which is what I point out is possible.

Comment: @Pete I stand corrected!

Answer (score 17):

You can't do it by C#, but you can edit MSIL.

IL code of your **Main** method:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] class MsilEditing.A a)
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: newobj instance void MsilEditing.B::.ctor()
    L_0006: stloc.0 
    L_0007: ldloc.0 
    L_0008: callvirt instance void MsilEditing.A::X()
    L_000d: nop 
    L_000e: ret 
}
```

You should change opcode in L_0008 from **callvirt** to **call**

```
L_0008: call instance void MsilEditing.A::X()
```

Answer (score 14):

It's impossible if the method is declared in the derived class as `overrides`. to do that, the method in the derived class should be declared as `new`:

```
public class Base {

    public virtual string X() {
        return "Base";
    }
}
public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public new string X()
    {
        return "Derived 1";
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base 
{
    public override string X() {
        return "Derived 2";
    }
}

Derived1 a = new Derived1();
Base b = new Derived1();
Base c = new Derived2();
a.X(); // returns Derived 1
b.X(); // returns Base
c.X(); // returns Derived 2
```

[See fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9L4PYY)

Comment: I feel this should be the answer to this problem. If you change the way you are "overriding" the method to making it a new one with the same signature, then everything else should work fine.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it, but not at the point you've specified. Within the context of `B`, you may invoke `A.X()` by calling `base.X()`.

Answer (score 9):

You can't, and you shouldn't. That's what polymorphism is for, so that each object has its own way of doing some "base" things.

Answer (score 6):

I konow it's history question now. But for other googlers: you could write something like this. But this requires change in base class what makes it useless with external libraries.

```
class A
{
  void protoX() { Console.WriteLine("x"); }
  virtual void X() { protoX(); }
}

class B : A
{
  override void X() { Console.WriteLine("y"); }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    A b = new B();
    // Call A.X somehow, not B.X...
    b.protoX();


  }
```