# How close can one simulate the assigning of base in C#

Tags: c#, oop, functional-programming

I want create a `Func` that is a two-argument encapsulation of the `base.Equals` method for some derived class.  One argument of the `Func` is the instance in/on which `base.Equals` is called and the other argument of the `Func` is passed into `base.Equals`.  I cannot place requirements on the base class, but I can place some on the derived class.  For example, I can require the derived class to expose `base.Equals`.

This would be easy if the keyword `base` could be used in like the keyword `this`, but it doesn't.  See my failed attempt below.

```
using System;
namespace MyNamespace {
  class BaseClass { }
  class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IEquatable<DerivedClass> {
    Func<DerivedClass, DerivedClass, bool> baseEquals;
    DerivedClass() {
      DerivedClass referenceToThis = this;
      BaseClass referenceToBase = referenceToThis.base; // doesn't compile
      this.baseEquals = (x, y) => x.Equals(y);
    }
    public bool Equals(DerivedClass that) => this.baseEquals(this, that);
  }
}
```

Based on my current understanding of C#, I think what want to do is not allowed.

> Is there C# that has the same semantics as my example but is valid?
>
> If not, how close can one get to this example?  That is, to what extent can the `base.Equals` method be encapsulated?

**Edit to add an example**

```
using System;
using FluentEquality.Common.EqualityCompareres;
namespace MyNamespace {
  class MyProgram {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var instance0 = new LeafClass(0);
      var instance1 = new LeafClass(1);
      var baseEqualsMethod = SomeMagicalMethodYetToBeDefined(instance0.BaseEqualsMethod, instance0.BaseGetHashCodeMethod);
      equalityComparer.Equals(instance0, instance1); // should output: BaseClass 0
      equalityComparer.Equals(instance1, instance0); // should output: BaseClass 1
      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
  class BaseClass {
    protected int Id;
    public BaseClass(int id) { this.Id = id; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { Console.WriteLine(nameof(BaseClass) + " " + Id); return false; }
    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
  }
  class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
    public DerivedClass(int id) : base(id) { }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { Console.WriteLine(nameof(DerivedClass) + " " + Id); return false; }
    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
    public Func<object, bool> BaseEqualsMethod => base.Equals;
    public Func<int> BaseGetHashCodeMethod => base.GetHashCode;
  }
  class LeafClass : DerivedClass {
    public LeafClass(int id) : base(id) { }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { Console.WriteLine(nameof(LeafClass) + " " + Id); return false; }
    public override int GetHashCode() => base.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems fishy to me that you want to always call the `base.Equals`, without knowing the type. Could you explain the broad solution you're looking for? I'm sure there's a better way to approach the issue. Forgetting that `Equals` is a method on `object`, what happens if they pass you `BaseClass`, where there is no `base.Equals`?

Comment: At a quick glance, this would appear to lead to a Stack Overflow exception if slightly modified.  Perhaps if you explained what you actually need, you'd get a better answer.

Comment: @Rob Of course I don't want to always call `base.Equals`. I only did that to create a minimum working example.  I want to create an implantation of IEqualityComparer that uses the base Equals and GeyHashCode methods for a type. Your last question raised a good point in that whatever I build will also need to work for the type `object`, which has no base.

Comment: @David I don't care if the MWE has a stack overflow.  I only included the IEquatable<>.Equals method definition so show the evaluation if the `Func`.

Comment: In your new example, did you intend `baseEqualsMethod` and `equalityComparer` to be the same thing?

Comment: @Rob Where did your answer go?  I know it didn't work, but I was going to play with it to see I could get it to work.

Comment: @TysonWilliams Your comment revealed a fatal problem with the answer -  and I don't feel comfortable keeping answers up which are incorrect. However, I've been playing with another approach which may suit your use-case. Once it's tidied up, I'll post it as a new answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, my other answer was fatally flawed in that it had the same problem as reflection did - the overridden method would be called, regardless of which method you attempted to invoke.

The following is an example using the technique found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358250/563532) to create a dynamic method which *does* allow you to specify which overridden method is to be called. The benefit of this approach is that you do not need the classes to expose the base method, and in-fact - you don't need to modify the classes at all.

```
class BaseClass
{
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BaseClass");
        return false;
    }
}

class DerivedClass
{
    public bool Equals(DerivedClass other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass Equals");
        return true;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DerivedClass Object Equals");
        return true;
    }
}

static class MyComparerThing<TParentType>
{
    public static bool Equals(TParentType left, TParentType right) => MyComparerThing<TParentType, TParentType, object>.Equals(left, right);
}
static class MyComparerThing<TParentType, TOnType>
{
    public static bool Equals(TOnType left, TOnType right) => MyComparerThing<TParentType, TOnType, object>.Equals(left, right);
}
static class MyComparerThing<TParentType, TOnType, TCompareType>
{
    static Func<TOnType, TOnType, bool> baseEquals;

    static MyComparerThing()
    {
        DynamicMethod dm = new DynamicMethod("BaseFoo", typeof(bool), new Type[] { typeof(TOnType), typeof(TOnType) }, typeof(TOnType));
        ILGenerator gen = dm.GetILGenerator();
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);

        var method = typeof(TParentType).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(TCompareType) });
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        baseEquals = (Func<TOnType, TOnType, bool>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TOnType, TOnType, bool>));
    }

    public static bool Equals(TOnType left, TOnType right) => baseEquals(left, right);
}
```

Testing with the following:

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new DerivedClass();
    var b = new DerivedClass();

    //The generic parameters in order are:
    //1. The type which implements the desired method
    //2. The type of the arguments (a and b)
    //3. The parameter argument of the method (object vs DerivedClass)

    //The following three are equivelant, using 'default' generic arguments
    MyComparerThing<DerivedClass>.Equals(a, b);
    MyComparerThing<DerivedClass, DerivedClass>.Equals(a, b);
    MyComparerThing<DerivedClass, DerivedClass, object>.Equals(a, b);

    //This will print the method declared in BaseClass. a and b are still DerivedClass instances. This is the one you're wanting to use
    MyComparerThing<BaseClass, DerivedClass>.Equals(a, b);

    //This will print the method declared in DerivedClass, with the DerivedClass overload
    MyComparerThing<DerivedClass, DerivedClass, DerivedClass>.Equals(a, b);

    //This will print the method declared in DerivedClass, with the object overload
    MyComparerThing<DerivedClass, DerivedClass, object>.Equals(a, b);

}
```

Prints:

```
DerivedClass Object Equals
DerivedClass Object Equals
DerivedClass Object Equals
BaseClass
DerivedClass Equals
DerivedClass Object Equals
```

I've chosen to use generics to decide which override to call - but this can be changed to pull the information from elsewhere, or alternatively, to hardcode it. 
If you want to always call the base method, you'd need to modify the above to write something along the lines of `typeof(TOnType).BaseType.GetMethod("Equals", ....)`

Comment: Tested and works.  An advantage of @StriplingWarrior 's answer is that it is not necessary to specify the type on which the overloaded method exists.  Suppose someone refactored the inheritance by (1) adding another Equals overload on a type between `BaseClass` and `DerivedClass`, (2) removing the overload from `BaseClass`, or (3) changing the name of `BaseClass`.  These would be cause compile or, even worse, runtime errors for the users of this code.  To avoid this, couldn't we look at the MSIL generated by StriplingWarrior's solution and use that?  Surely it isn't using `callvert`.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: In the IL code generated by my answer `DerivedClass.Equals` in my answer does a `call` to `BaseClass.Equals`. This answer does the same thing via `gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method)`. Rob used generics to specify the parent class for the sake of this example, but you could easily determine it using `typeof(TOnType).BaseType` instead of `typeof(TParentType)`. I think the time has come to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior It only happens to be the same in this case.  In general, the most recent overload of `Object.Equals(object)` could be on any parent class in the inheritance hierarchy.  Using reflection, I could write the code needed to determine the correct type to pass in to Rob's solution (as an argument of type `Type` instead of a type parameter).  Clearly the compiler contains this code.  I wonder if it is available to be called.  Anyway, the solutions by Rob and yourself definitely clarify how the `base` keyword works and what can be accomplished with it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could cast this to your base class and get similar behavior.

Comment: What if I don't know the derived class until runtime? Then I wouldn't know what base class to cast to. (Updated question to say this.)

Comment: @TysonWilliams: How can you define a derived class without knowing what its base class is at compile-time?

Comment: The base and derived classes are defined elsewhere by others.  I only want to depend on the type, not the dentition of the type.

Comment: I may have misspoken here.  I tried to update the question to clarify.  In particular, I cannot place any requirements on the base class, but I can require those that implement the derived class to jump through some hoops.  As a primary design goal, I would like things to be type safe (at least between the API boundary between the code in the derived class and the code that creates the `Func` that I want), so casting is out of the question.  If it came to that, then I would rather sacrifice the design in other ways.

Comment: @TysonWilliams You could preserve type safety with the as operator and null checking/propagation. This would meet the requirement of only the derived class jumping through hoops.

Comment: Sure, but I also want to do as much of the work in my code as well. Even so, I still don't see how your suggestion could be made to work. Can you code it up?

Comment: @TysonWilliams Gave a very simple example

Comment: Nowhere are you encapsulating `base.Equals` as a two-argument `Func`.

Comment: @TysonWilliams I am just giving an example of how to do it generally, extending it to encapsulate a two-argument func is fairly trivial from there.

Comment: On the contrary, I think it so complicated that I don't know how to do it.  I would be extremely appreciative if you could humor me and provide this trivial extension you speak of.

Comment: @TysonWilliams Sure thing, going to be a few hours though, heading home soon.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: When you say that you can require the derived class to jump through hoops, can one of those hoops be to require that the derived classes aren't allowed to override `Equals(object)`?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior No, I don't want to require them to change what the publicly expose. As I commented in your answer though, i would be willing to have them add a private method.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're overcomplicating things. If I understand correctly, all you're really trying to do is implement `IEquatable<DerivedClass>`, but delegate to the `base.Equals()` method:

```
  class BaseClass { }
  class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IEquatable<DerivedClass> {
    public bool Equals(DerivedClass that) => base.Equals(that);
  }
```

### Update

If you are willing to require your child classes to implement a method exposing their base class's method, then you can just invoke that method from your equality comparer:

```
void Main()
{
    // Output: "Base"
    new BaseEqualityComparer<DerivedClass>().Equals(
        new DerivedClass(),
        new DerivedClass());
}

class BaseClass 
{
    public override bool Equals(object that)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base");
        return base.Equals(that);
    }
}
class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IEquatable<DerivedClass> 
{
    public override bool Equals(object that)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived");
        return base.Equals(that);
    }
    public bool Equals(DerivedClass that) => base.Equals(that);
}
class BaseEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> 
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T val1, T val2)
    {
        return val1.Equals(val2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T val)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

However, if you're not willing to make that a requirement for all the base classes, I'm pretty sure C# won't let you do this directly. Rob's answer shows that it is possible to capture the call to the `base` method's implementation, so it's clearly something that the runtime is capable of. I believe if you're willing to emit IL code, you should be able to do what you want by [issuing a `call` instruction (rather than a `callvirt` instruction) to the base method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30297884/120955).

Comment: No, that is definitely not what I am trying to do.

Comment: @TysonWilliams Based on your comment on the question - *I want to create an implantation of IEqualityComparer that uses the base Equals and GeyHashCode methods for a type* - How does that differ from this answer?

Comment: The simplest way to show that is to observe that your answer doesn't even include the string "IEqualityComparer".

Comment: @TysonWilliams Okay - but then I fail to understand how it will be both an `IEqualityComparer` *and* an `IEquatable`. If it's an IEqualityComparer, then it's hard-coding the fact that you're calling `base.Equals` (even without knowing the type). But your comment on the question is says you don't always want to call `base.Equals`. Could you perhaps show us a list of use-cases and what the method *should* return for each? Because as I see it, there's no clear explanation of how it should behave.

Comment: I don't care about IEquatable<>.  I just included that as a reasonable example that evaluates the `Func`.  I really want to create that `Func`.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: To be fair, your comment about `IEqualityComparer` was not there when I answered this. All I saw was that you thought this would be easy if only `base` worked the way you thought it should, and you provided a code sample that implemented `IEquatable<>`. I think Rob is right: you'll be far more likely to get a good answer if you spend more time defining the problem you're really trying to solve, including code showing how you'd expect to use this `Func` you're hoping to create.

Comment: I am really trying to solve many problems in life. In this context, I want to create a class that implements IEquatityComparer<T> by delegating to the class from which T derives.  However, I am explicitly not asking about that. Instead, while looking for an answer to that question myself, I encountered this quotation about the expressiveness of the `base` keyword in C#.  In the example I have, I want that `Func` but with valid C#.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: If you're willing to stipulate that each sub-class has to implement a certain method a specific way, you could require them to each expose a method that invokes the `base` method. If not, I think the only way is to emit IL code. See my update.

Comment: You solution does not encapsulate `base.Equals` into a two-argument `Func`.  That is what I want.

Comment: Furthermore, your solution current suffers from the same issue as Rob's, namely, the only reason that `BaseClass.Equals` is called is because `DerivedClass.Equals` differs to it.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: Getting a two-argument Func from my solution is trivial--I assumed you'd be able to figure it out: `Func<DerivedClass, DerivedClass, bool> baseEquals = new BaseEqualityComparer<DerivedClass>().Equals;` Furthermore, whereas Rob's solution has a call to `Equals(object)` that defers to the base class because the derived class does not override that method, in my solution the derived class *does* override that method and you would see a different output if its `Equals(object)` implementation ever got invoked.

Comment: Ok, I see what you have done.  I was confused by the fact that both methods are called `Equals` and one of them calls and returns `base.Equals`.  I think it would be clearer to return `false` instead.  Anyway, I now see what you meant by your twice-previous comment.  I would prefer to not place requirements on the their API to the world.  Or think of it this way...can you do this while only exposing `BaseEqualityComparer<>` instead of the sausage used to make it?

Comment: Actually, I think you're on to something. If you just make this method private, then it doesn't change the interface of the class. Then you can create the `BaseEqualityComparer` inside and expose it outside.

Comment: Indeed, it works just fine to make private the method exposing `base.Equals`.  I could be satisfied with this solution, but I would love it if it sufficed to have `DerivedClass` pass `base.Equals` and `base.GetHashCode` to me and I construct the `EqualityComparer`.  If that were possible, it would certainly minimize the work needed to be done and the number of auxiliary method definitions in `DerivedClass`.

Comment: @TysonWilliams: Rob took the time to code up an example of the IL-code-emitting solution I made reference to in my last paragraph. That's definitely a more elegant solution.

Comment: Indeed.  I haven't had the time yet to read the link in your last paragraph or try Rob's new answer.  I really do like the simplicity of your solution though and a bit ashamed that I didn't think of it myself.  I think I missed seeing it because I didn't consider placing more requirements on `DerivedClass` that just passing `base.Equals` to me.

Comment: Oh, actually, I did look at your link, but had never seen MSIL before and didn't want to go down the path of directly using it.  In contrast though, I am ok with this MSIL generator that Rob is using.