# Casting object of inherited class to instance of inheriting type

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-core, .net-5

I have the following code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Outer outer = new Outer();
        Inner inner = new Inner();

        Outer outer2 = new Inner();
        Inner inner2 = new Outer();
    }
}
public class Outer { }
public class Inner : Outer { }
```

I get the compiler error when assigning `new Outer()` to `inner2` because it's of type `Inner`. I understand that it's to do with the inheritance but I can not figure out why because the contents are the same. Also, how can I force it to be cast to `Inner`.

I have tried

```
(inner)new Outer();
new Outer() as Inner;
```

But it threw an exception about conversion in the former and became null in the latter. Not sure what to google for to find out. I mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39250249/8186652) but the exact opposite.

Comment: Outer is not an Inner, and you can never force it to become an Inner when it isn't an Inner. The contents are irrelevant.

Comment: It's a lot easier if you name things `Base` and `Sub`, btw.  A variable of type `Outer` can refer to an instance of an `Outer` or to an instance of any subclass of `Outer` (in this case, `Inner`).  But, `Inner` is a _specialization_ of `Outer`, so a variable of `Inner` can only refer to an `Inner` object (or any subclasses of `Inner`).  Just because `Inner` doesn't do anything special while it's specializing `Outer`, doesn't mean it's not a specialization.  Consider the case where you have what you have, and it compiles, but then you add a member to `Inner`.  It would suddenly break

Comment: Yes, the names are super confusing. If just playing around learning C#, I'd suggest experimenting with a class hierarchy named like e.g. Animal -> Insect -> Butterfly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subclass is of type base class, but not the opposite. consider renaming them to

```
class Dog {}
class GermanShepard : Dog {}
```

This makes it clear that A German Sheppard is definitely a dog. But a dog is not necessarily a German Shepard.

writing the following is not possible, since the new dog could end up being another type of dog.

```
GermanShepard fred = new Dog();  //error!!
```

It might be a Shitzu or a Labrador. But you can always cast a German Shepard to a dog. Similarly you can always cast a Labrador to a dog.