# Add extra implementation in overrided version of a virtual method

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

```
virtual void MyMethod()
{
    DoOneThing();
}
```

I want to implement `DoAnotherThing()` along with `DoOneThing()` here-

```
override void MyMethod()
{
    //DoOneThing() also.
    DoAnotherThing();
}
```

Is it possible at all?

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. I updated my question.

Comment: Just use `base.MyMethod();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call the 'base implementation' of an overridden virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334254/how-can-i-call-the-base-implementation-of-an-overridden-virtual-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here small example

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoOneThing");
    }
}

class MegaFoo : Foo
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        base.MyMethod(); // call Foo.MyMethod
        Console.WriteLine("DoAnotherThing");
    }
}
```