# Understanding of inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

```
namespace WebApplication1.Class
{
    public class DailySalaryCalculator
    {
        public void Calculate()
        {
        }
    }

    public class WeeklySalaryCalculator : DailySalaryCalculator
    {
        public void Calculate()
        {
        }
    }

    public class MonthlySalaryCalculator : WeeklySalaryCalculator
    {
        public void Calculate()
        {
            //I want to execute Calculate() of Daily Salary Calculator here.
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call `Calculate` method of `DailySalaryCalculator` directly From `MonthlySalaryCalculator` without creating a object of `DailySalaryCalculator`.

How can I do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It doesn't look as Objective-C code. Are you sure you tagged the post correctly?

Comment: I am trying to understand concept of inheritance in c# and i didn't found relevant tag so I have used closet one.

Comment: Did you forgot `virtual` and `override` keywords? Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method

Comment: Good OOP design says that you shouldn't bypass a layer you inherit from. Why do you need to call the daily salary calculator from the monthly one and not through the weekly one?

Comment: I'm just speculating here, but could it be because a month isn't really a container of whole weeks? If so then you shouldn't inherit this way, instead making the Monthly class inherit from the Daily class, making the Weekly and Monthly class two ways to group days.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the improper use of inheritance. First of all, you need to understand what you're trying to accomplish, in this case you want to calculate salaries. Daily, Weekly or Monthly are strategies for doing the calculation.

You should consider each class an **encapsulation** of the business rule used to implement the calculations. Weekly makes no design sense to inherit from Daily, the same is for Monthly and Weekly.

The better way is this

```
public abstract AbstractSalaryCalculator
{
     //note that the calculation returns something, as this is basically a service
     public virtual decimal Calculate();
 }

 public class DailySalaryCalculator:AbstractSalaryCalculator
 {
    public override decimal Calculate()
    {
         //do stuff
        //return result
    }
 }

 public class WeeklySalaryCalculator:AbstractSalaryCalculator
 {
       public override decimal Calculate()
    {
         //do stuff
        //return result
    } 
 }

public class MonthlySalaryCalculator:AbstractSalaryCalculator
 {
     //probably is better for the daily calculator to be injected via the constructor
     public override decimal Calculate(DailySalaryCalculator daily)
    {
         //use daily to do stuff
        //return result
    } 
 }

var daily= new DailySalaryCalculator();
var monthly=new MonthlySalaryCalculator();
var result=monhtly.Calculate(daily);
```

### Explanation

The point is to define calculators that handle a specific aspect of the business rules and then (re)use them in a decoupled way. All are calculators but a Weekly **is not** a Daily. A Weekly/Monthly can **use** a Daily because this is the relation between these concepts.

Inheritance means the child *is* a more specific concept of the parent's. In your use case, there is nothing more specific, they're just different ways to calculate a salary. 
That's why in my code, the monthly calc *makes use* of the daily one, but it doesn't inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by below code snippet,

Just ***cast the current object with DailySalaryCalculator class***

```
public class DailySalaryCalculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {

    }
}

public class WeeklySalaryCalculator : DailySalaryCalculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {

    }
}

public class MonthlySalaryCalculator : WeeklySalaryCalculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {
        (this.MemberwiseClone() as DailySalaryCalculator).Calculate();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what have you tried.

But below is working sample code for me.

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MonthlySalaryCalculator obj = new MonthlySalaryCalculator();

        obj.Calculate();

        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class DailySalaryCalculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DailySalaryCalculator");
    }
}

public class WeeklySalaryCalculator : DailySalaryCalculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WeeklySalaryCalculator");
    }
}

public class MonthlySalaryCalculator : WeeklySalaryCalculator
{
    public void Calculate()
    {
        (this.MemberwiseClone() as DailySalaryCalculator).Calculate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by [overriding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx) the original `Calculate()` method that must be declared as [Virtual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) (to allow overriding it in inheriting classes).

To keep the code of the original method and add something to it, you should use the [base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) keyword to call the original method's behavior.

Your code should look as follows :

```
namespace WebApplication1.Class
{
    public class DailySalaryCalculator
    {
        public virtual void Calculate()
        {
        }
    }

    public class WeeklySalaryCalculator : DailySalaryCalculator
    {
        public override void Calculate()
        {
        }
    }

    public class MonthlySalaryCalculator : WeeklySalaryCalculator
    {
        public override void Calculate()
        {
            //I want to execute Calculate() of Daily Salary Calculator here.
            //Yes do this :

            base.Calculate();

            //Now, Add your additional code here
        }
    }
}
```

**Note !! :** that you don't need to re-write the keyword `virtual` in the `WeeklySalaryCalculator`'s `Calculate()` method, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250212/2002048) explains well :

> You can declare a certain method as virtual only once, but you can
>   override it as many times as you want - an override is not final, and
>   it does not limit classes that inherit from the first overriding
>   class.