# Using virtual and override for the same method

Tags: c#, overriding, virtual

I want to make a method in a C# program that is overriding an existing virtual method but also keep the method virtual so any class that inherits from it can further extend the method.

Can I use both override and virtual in the method declaration? If so, which order do I put them in?

**For example**

```
public override virtual void method()
```

OR

```
public virtual override void method()
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you are overriding a method, it is already virtual

Comment: you have use "public override void method()" in sub child class like the way you override method in child class. Read on the [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18734/Method-Overriding-in-C) for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250134/cant-use-virtual-and-override-on-the-same-method-in-c-sharp) to explain what you're asking. Basically, if you make a method in your base class `virtual`, any derived classes will be able to override that method (no matter how deep the derivation). There is no need to continue to specify virtual for the method in your derived classes (in fact, I don't think you can do it). Use the `sealed` specifier to disallow the method from being overridden in derived classes.

Comment: Thanks you that makes so much more sense. Its nice that the language provides so much functionality for handling these specific circumstances

Answer (score 1):

If a method is virtual, any child class can override it. You do not need to redeclare it as virtual.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual