# How to call base method from derived class instance in C#?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have C# code, base `class A` and derived `class B`:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void print() {Console.WriteLine("a"); }
}
public class B:A
{
    public override void print() { Console.WriteLine("b"); }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a= new B();
    //In c++ I can use .Base:: to call base method from derived class instance
    a.Base::print();
}
```

I can't modify these two classes and I don't know what can I do in C#, any suggestion?

---

Additionally, thanks to everyone joining into this discussion, and I would like to clarify why I need this behavior:

In .net framework, we have an interface **IPostBackDataHandler** to handle postback. and in there is a method

```
public bool LoadPostData( string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection )
```

When I implement it and test, I find sometimes the given postback type of **postCollection** is **NameValueCollection** ,while other time it's **HttpValueCollection** (a derived class of *NameValueCollection*)

Then,if it is a type of **HttpValueCollection**, when I get item from it, eg. **postCollection['ControlID']** and I input *html* in this control, **HttpValueCollection.get_item()** will always validate the input and view it as a defect. While **NameValueCollection.get_item()** won't

I don't want it operate validation automatically, at least **I** should decide whether it should be validated, should I?

Comment: maybe [dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323401/how-to-call-base-base-method) [dup2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438939/is-there-any-way-to-call-the-parent-version-of-an-overridden-method-c-net)

Comment: Essentially, you want the compiler to emit `call` rather than `callvirt`. Unfortunately, there's no current means of asking for that directly in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to access base method from outside the derived class.
You can either write a method in derived class that will call base method like this:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override void print() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }

    public void basePrint() { base.print(); }
}
```

Or you can user `Reflection` to get base method definition and invoke it but it's rather ugly.
Here is how to create `DynamicMethod` that calls base `print` method:

```
// Get MethodInfo of the base method
var methodInfo = typeof(A).GetMethod("Print", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

// Create DynamicMethod based on the methodInfo
var dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("BasePrint", methodInfo.ReturnType, new[] { methodInfo.DeclaringType }, methodInfo.DeclaringType);
// Create ILGenerator for the dynamic method
var il = dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();

// Emit argument with index 0 - DeclaringType
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
// Emit method call
il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, methodInfo, null);
// Emit method return value
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

// Invoke method with target...
var b = new B();
dynamicMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {b});

// ... or create a delegate and invoke method without target
var action = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action)) as Action;
action.Invoke();
```

**Note that** it'll work only for parameterless method. If you want to call method with parameters you'll have to put their types into the array with the `DeclaringType` and later emit all of them. Also you'll have to create delegate of type `Action<parameterTypes` or `Func<returnType, parameterTypes>` if the method returns something.

Comment: It's pity that I can't modify the class itself. I guess even _Reflection_ can only achieve the override method class B? Can it?

Comment: Well it's possible. You could get methodInfo from base class and construct the `DynamicMethod`. Then, using `ILGenerator` you should probably be able to Invoke this method. I don't know the context, but maybe you could create another class (let's say `C`) that derives from `A` and then call `base.print()` inside it?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the explanation of how to generate and create dynamicMethod.

Answer (score 3):

You can only call your base class's methods from the derived class (`B`) by doing:

```
base.print();
```

I don't think there is a way to do what you want to do, because it kind of breaks the point of polymorphism.

However, you can *hide* the `print` method in `A` by doing this in `B`:

```
new public void print() { Console.WriteLine("b"); }
```

This way, this code:

```
A a= new B();
a.print();
```

will call the `print` in `A`.

Comment: in which namespace does `Base` exist?

Comment: there is no such thing in c#

Comment: @LeiYang don't use the capital B, it's not a class it's a keyword https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx

Comment: You are right, but I can't edit the class itself.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everyone! 
Finally I realize this behavior need using reflection and delegate, like *nocodename* showing, here I find a similar method.

```
A a = new B();
var ptr = typeof(A).GetMethod("Print", new[] { typeof(_inputParameter) }).MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
var baseGetItem = (Func<String, String>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Func<String, String>), a, ptr);
String postedValue = baseGetItem(_parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call base `print` outside of a class `B` i.e. from `Main` method due to way how `override` works in c#. However if you want to have possibility to do that, you should consider to *shadow* print method in class `B`:

```
public class B:A
{
    public new void print() { Console.WriteLine("b"); }
}
```

With `new` keyword class *shadows* member from parent class, so your line of code will work:

```
A a= new B();
a.print(); //prints "a"
```

and

```
B b= new B();
b.print(); //prints "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the base method when you override it in the inherited. You can make the method in B to be `new` instead of `override`, but you lose the implementation.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Print() { Console.WriteLine("a"); }
}

public class B: A
{
    public new void Print() { Console.WriteLine("b"); }
}
```

This way when you call

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    A a = new B();
    a.Print(); // prints "a"
}
```

Otherwise, you can call base.Print() in the overridden method.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Print() { Console.WriteLine("a"); }
}

public class B: A
{
    public override void Print() 
    {
        base.Print();
        Console.WriteLine("b"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of override is that you will not call the base class's function.
If you want to call A.print - use A object, if you want to call B.print use B object, and if you want an object that can use some of that and some of that - create it separately or use functions with different names, that might solve your problem.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but maybe you would like to read about [Visitor Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm)

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call base class method from derived class by using "base" keywork:

see example,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B obj= new B();
            obj.print();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public virtual void print() { Console.WriteLine("a"); }
    }
    public class B : A
    {
        public override void print() 
        {
            base.print();
            Console.WriteLine("b"); 
        }
    }

}
```

hope you understand! Thank u

Answer (score -2):

```
var obj = new B();
obj.Print(); // overriden method
(obj as A).Print(); // base method
```

Comment: Since the `print` method is virtual, I doubt that this works?!? See also [this .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zxrFq9).

Comment: It doesn't. It probably won't even compile. But it does call the base method.

Comment: it calls the overridden method.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!