# Powershell Class Inheritance Behavior

Tags: powershell, class, inheritance

I'm attempting to utilize PowerShell's inheritance to create a class that inherits from an existing class and I am not seeing the expected behavior based on [various](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-5.1#inheritance-in-powershell-classes) [sources](https://xainey.github.io/2016/powershell-classes-and-concepts/#inheritance).

Here's a brief example highlighting the problem:

```
class child : System.Xml.XmlDocument {
    [String] ToString(){
        return 'ChildString'
    }

    [void] LoadXml([string]$content) {
        Write-Host 'LoadXml'
        ([System.Xml.XmlDocument]$this).LoadXml($content)
    }
}
```

If I run

```
Write-Host 'XMLDocument Object'
$xml=New-Object xml
$xml.ToString()

Write-Host 'Inherited Object'
$child=New-Object child
$child.ToString()
```

The console output is

```
XMLDocument Object
#document
Inherited Object
#document
```

indicating that the `ToString()` method of the child class is NOT being utilized.

On the opposite end of the spectrum, if I call `$child.LoadXml('<a>Hello</a>')`  then I get infinite recursion, implying that the call to the parent object is failing in that method.

Based on what I've been able to find I would not expect these methods to behave this way and I was hoping that someone could help me understand what I am missing. I am generally more used to Python; however, for security reasons I can't implement this code in another programming language (I can't install software on the computer this is to be run on).

Thanks!

---

Here's the results of `$PSversionTable.PSVersion` for reference:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  909
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, the call to `ToString()` is overridden by additional type data attached to their common ancestor `System.Xml.XmlNode`:

```
PS C:\> Get-TypeData -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNode

TypeName           Members                                                            
--------           -------                                                            
System.Xml.XmlNode {[ToString, System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.CodeMethodData]}
```

You can use `Remove-TypeData` to remove it at runtime:

```
Remove-TypeData -TypeName System.Xml.XmlNode
```

You should now see your `child` object invoke its own method and the `XmlDocument` object invoke `ToString()` as inherited from `System.Object`:

```
XMLDocument Object
System.Xml.XmlDocument
Inherited Object
ChildString
```

Comment: That's really interesting and solved 99% of my issues. I will definitely have to look into TypeData a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks! Although annoying, I believe this member resolution order is essential to the behavior of ETS. The only bug I see in the original question is the `LoadXml` thing.

Comment: I posted an issue re `LoadXml` calling itself instead of the base class: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6386

Answer (score 1):

[Mathias R. Jessen's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49259649/45375) explains and resolves the **problem with the shadowed `.ToString()` method**.
Even though **the behavior may be obscure, it appears to be by design**: PowerShell's [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml), which allows customization of .NET types, gives precedence to such customizations even in *derived* classes.

By contrast, **the inability to call the base class method from your `.LoadXml()` method smells like a *bug***, reported in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6386) *[fixed as of at least PowerShell Core v6.1.0]*, and it sounds like the [bug is specific to classes that derive from `System.Xml.XmlNode`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6386#issuecomment-372869624).

Here's a **workaround**, gratefully adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838794/45375):

```
class child : System.Xml.XmlDocument {
  [void] LoadXml([string]$content) {
    Write-Host 'LoadXml'
    # Get a function pointer to the base class method...
    $funcPtr = [System.Xml.XmlDocument].GetMethod('LoadXml', [string]).MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer() 
    # ...and invoke it with this instance.
    [Activator]::CreateInstance([Action[string]], $this, $funcPtr).Invoke($content)
  }
}
```

Comment: For my purposes, I can get around utilizing the LoadXml function, it was just quite surprising when I tested it that it behaved that way. Combined with the other behavior, I thought that I was going insane. Anyway, I tested this workaround and it does solve the problem. I wish I could mark both answers as accepted. Thanks!