# How to call the base class method?

Tags: c#, oop

We have the following code:

```
  public class A
  {
    protected virtual void Method()
    {
      Console.Write("A");
    }
  }

  public class B : A
  {
    protected override void Method()
    {
      Console.Write("B");
    }
  }

  public class C : B
  {
    public void Some()
    {
      //How to call Method() from class A?
    }
  }
```

How to call `Method()` from class A  in `Some()` method from class C?

**We will assume that A and B are classes from the library and we can not change them.**

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/438952/8081796

Comment: i don't think there's another way beside method hiding

Comment: Without knowing anything about the "library" - it looks like you should be deriving from A rather than B. If the rest of the class shall behave the "B" way, you could use composition and proxy all methods but this one to an internal instance of B. ("Internal" as in "private") But really: This looks like a case for design review to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I call the 'base implementation' of an overridden virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334254/how-can-i-call-the-base-implementation-of-an-overridden-virtual-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` overrides `Method()` and `A` its marked as virtual and protected, the only way to call it (in its current format) is if `B` calls it somehow

```
public class B : A 
{
   protected override void Method()
   {
      base.Method();
      Console.Write("B");
   }
}
```

Or derived from `A` directly

```
public class C : A
{
   public void Some()
   {
      Method();
   }
}
```

[virtual (C# Reference) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer, or
>   event declaration and allow for it to be overridden in a derived
>   class. For example, this method can be overridden by any class that
>   inherits it:

**Furthermore**

> When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is
>   checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most
>   derived class is called, which might be the original member, if no
>   derived class has overridden the member.

[protected (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected)

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class
>   instances.

Comment: We will assume that A and B are classes from the library and we can not change them.

Comment: It turns out that this is impossible?

Comment: @StepanIvanenko yes indeed, unless you can change the classes or change your requirements

Answer (score 0):

If you `really` want `Method` of `A` to be called here (without changing implementation of `A` or `B`'s `Method`), you have to make below changes.

1. Change access specifier of `Method` of `B` class to `new` from `override`.

   > `override` will override the base class method. Making it `new` won't do it.
2. Change access specifier of `A` and `B` class `Method`s to `public` instead of `protected`

   > `protected` members of `A` won't be accessible inside your `C` class.

With this changes, check out below code. You will see that `Method` from class `A` is getting called.

```
static void Main()
{
    var c = new C();
    c.Some();
    Console.ReadKey();
}
public class A
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        Console.Write("A");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public new void Method()
    {
        Console.Write("B");
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public void Some()
    {
        //How to call Method() from class A?
        ((A)this).Method();
    }
}
```

*If you cannot make the changes described as above, then I'm afraid you can't call `A`'s `Method` :O .*

Comment: We will assume that A and B are classes from the library and we can not change them.

Comment: `((A)this).Method();` is not compiled :)

Comment: have you copied my full code?  you must have missed changes 1 & 2. It's working for me for `.Net 4.6.1`. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Paritosh Maharaj, `class A` and `class B` is library classes and we can not change them.

Comment: @StepanIvanenko - that's what I have written in the last line and also in my last comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, because

> The implementation of a virtual member can be changed by an overriding
>   member in a derived class.

`B` change implementation of `A`, therefore `C` have only `B` implementation  as `base` and have not implementation of `A`.

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/438952/8081796