# accessing overridden method from derived class object

Tags: c#

Is it possible to access the method that has been overridden using the object of the derived class?

```
using System;


class Bclass
{
    public virtual int result(int a,int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
class Dclass:Bclass
{
    public override int result(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
}

public class Program
{

    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dclass obj1 = new Dclass();
        Console.WriteLine(obj1.result(10, 5));
    }

}
```

Is there a way to get the output as 15?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I call the 'base implementation' of an overridden virtual method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334254/how-can-i-call-the-base-implementation-of-an-overridden-virtual-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/override)

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the abstract or
>   virtual implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or
>   event.

---

`override` modifier are designed to extend functionality of `virtual` function. When ever you call overridden function with the help of derived class object it will call overridden function.

To answer your question,

> Is it possible to access the method that has been overridden using the
>   object of the derived class?

- There is **no** way to call virtual method **directly** using derived class object

---

Ways to call virtual method:

Approach 1:

Create a new function in derived class and call [`base.result()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base) from it.

```
public int BaseResult(int a, int b)
{
    return base.result(a, b);
}
```

and call `BaseResult()` using derived class instance

```
  Dclass obj1 = new Dclass();
  Console.WriteLine(obj1.BaseResult(10, 5));
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1xwZqC)

Approach 2:

Create instance of base class and from that access `virtual` method.

```
    Bclass obj2 = new Bclass();
    Console.WriteLine(obj2.result(10, 5));
```

Comment: *"There is **no** way to call virtual method directly using derived class object"* - there [is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32348369/1997232).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my answer I said *"There is **no** way to call virtual method **directly** using derived class object"*. Using reflection or using other techniques we can call it.

Comment: Agree. My eyes stops on that bold *no*.

Comment: @Sinatr, I updated my answer and highlighted **directly**

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to declare the base method as `virtual` for some reason, you could also achieve what you want by declaring the derived class method as `new`, thereby hiding the implementation when using it through an instance of the derived class.

At the same time, you can still access the base implementation by casting the object to the base class.

Following the example you provided:

```
class Bclass
{
    public int result(int a,int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}

class Dclass : Bclass
{
    public new int result(int a, int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    public int BaseResult(int a, int b)
    {
        return base.result(a, b);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dclass obj1 = new Dclass();
        Console.WriteLine(((Bclass)obj1).result(10, 5)); // 15
    }
}
```

More information about the differences between `override` and `new` can be found in this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords).